# Does request.session["name"] in Django creates a new list?

Tags: python, django, session-cookies, django-sessions

What does it mean when we write `request.session["tasks"]` and assign it to something in django views? Like in the script below in the index function `request.session["tasks"] = [ ]`,does that mean an empty list named `tasks` has been created for that particular session? and if so, where exactly all these session details are stored in django? and also what does `cleaned_data["task"]` in the `add` function is exactly doing in this script? I tried looking in the documentation but couldn't find any satisfactory information about this, so I'm sorry if this sounds a little stupid but I'm new to django and sometimes the syntax really confuses me,Any help is appreciated!

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django import forms
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.urls import reverse 
# Create your views here.

class NewTaskForm(forms.Form):
    task = forms.CharField(label = "New Task",min_length=8,max_length=16)
    priority = forms.IntegerField(label="Priority",min_value=1,max_value=5)



def index(request):
    if "tasks" not in request.session:
        request.session["tasks"] = []
    return render(request,"index.html",
    {
        "tasks":request.session["tasks"]
    })

def add(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        vari = NewTaskForm(request.POST)
        if vari.is_valid():
            task = vari.cleaned_data["task"]
            request.session["tasks"] += [task]
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("index"))
        else:
            return render(request,"other.html",
            {
                "form":vari
            })

    return render(request,"other.html",{
        "form" : NewTaskForm()
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Yes, It means an empty list named tasks has been created for that particular session. and django stores the session data in 'django_session' table. 


cleaned_data is used for validating the data.

# This line is used to pass the validated data from the form input.
task = vari.cleaned_data["task"]
```

Comment: okay but I tried calling the append method on it like this ``request.session["tasks"].append([task])`` but it's not working can you please tell me how to do that?